# Problems with netbeans top menu font

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

How to solve this problem?
Netbeans top menu fonts has been changed.
Default language is still en_US.
My netbeans version is 6.9.1.
I have added an screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have got a solution at last. I just changed my menu fonts from Windows appearance and everything is working fine now. Instead of Lucida Granade I'm using Verdana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **both** "Active" and "Inactive" menu fonts to the default font (Segoe UI) solve the problem.